# joint group with Telegram API python (telithon telegram )

Tags: python, telegram

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import ImportChatInviteRequest
api_id = ++++
api_hash = '+++++++++++++++++++++'
client = TelegramClient('+1 ++++++', api_id, api_hash)
client.connect()
updates = client(ImportChatInviteRequest('GQVuGUG5pPEBxM6tQAeqqA'))
```

I want joint this Group telegram (https://t.me/joinchat/GQVuGUG5pPEBxM6tQAeqqA)
But i have this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
updates = client(ImportChatInviteRequest('GQVuGUG5pPEBxM6tQAeqqA'))
   TypeError: 'TelegramClient' object is not callable
```

I use this script :https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/wiki/Joining-a-chat-or-channel

Comment: Evidently `client`, a `TelegramClient` instance, can't be called. Why are you calling it?

Comment: other command is good but when i want joint group and use ImportChatInviteRequest i see erorr

Comment: In that case you should raise an issue with the package maintainers, because assuming your `client` is the right thing the actual code disagrees with the documentation.

Comment: Tanx Lonami i upgrade telithon and is work...

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade telithon telegram with

```
pip install --upgrade telethon
```